# If statement not evaluating all the conditions and executing anyway

Tags: python

Ok so I am new to python and trying to learn how to code. I ran into an issue today that I don't understand. So this code executes as expected and prints the largest of the three numbers no matter what position the largest number is.

```
    if num1 >= num2 and num3:
        print(num1, 'Is the greatest number!')

    elif num2 >= num3 and num1:
        print(num2, 'Is the greatest number!')

    else:
        print(num3, 'Is the greatest number')
```

But if i change the elif statement to this:

```
    elif num2 >= num1 and num3:
        print(num2, 'Is the greatest number!')
```

Even if num3 is the largest the else statement will not execute and it will display the larger number of num1 or num2.

Comment: Try running with `num1 = 2`, `num2 = 1` and `num3 = 10`, the first snippet of code won't work. It will print "(2, 'Is the greatest number!')".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a misunderstanding in the way the keyword `and` works.

In python, `and` is used to separate two complete logical statements: `cond1 and cond2`. It first checks `cond1`. If `cond1` is `True`, it moves on to check `cond2`. If `cond2` is also `True`, then the whole statement evaluates to `True`.

When you do `if num1 >= num2 and num3`, you are actually asking python if the following is `True`:

1. `num1 >= num2`
2. `num3` exists and is not `0` (since it's a number)

It is ***not*** checking `if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3`.

So if `num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 3`, your conditional will still return `True` for `if num1 >= num2 and num3`.

The same concept applies to your problem conditional.

Comment: `num3` exists and is not **zero** (since these are numbers).

Comment: @alexis good point, I'll change that

Answer (score 2):

Your first version works purely by coincidence. You need to do

```
if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
    print(num1, 'Is the greatest number!')

elif num2 >= num3 and num2 >= num1:
    print(num2, 'Is the greatest number!')

else:
    print(num3, 'Is the greatest number')
```

Although, this will still print wrong info if any of the numbers are equal